# What's the correct syntax to use Count() with Order By for a related object?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to get a list of objects sorted by the count of related objects. I've tried all sorts of permutations of the code below but I can't seem to make it work. The code below is what I would have figured would work but it just gives me "Didn't understand relationship 'Children__r' in field path."

```
//Get up to ten active Parent instances sorted descending by the number of related Child instances.

List<Parent__c> mostPopulatedParents = [    
    SELECT Name, ID
    FROM Parent__c
    WHERE Active = TRUE
    ORDER BY COUNT(SELECT Id FROM Children__r) DESC
    LIMIT 10
];
```

(I've generalized this code to not include proprietary stuff for my employer but now it looks like a homework question.)

What's the correct syntax to use Count() with Order By for a related object?

Answer (score 1):

You use an AggregateResult query, as in:

```
AggregateResult[] results = [
  SELECT COUNT(Id), Parent__c Id
  FROM Child__c
  GROUP BY Parent__c
  ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC
  LIMIT 10
];
```

Once you have the top 10, if you need additional fields, use a second query to get additional fields.